# Where are substitution rules for formulas with quantifier in predicate logic derived from?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Let's denote A[x/y], where A is a formula and [x/y] has the definition of substituting x in the place of y.

The substitution rules for formulas involving quantifiers are then the following in predicate logic:

($\exists$x A)[y/x] = $\exists$x A

($\exists$x A)[y\k] = $\exists$x A[y\k], if x,k not present in the formula

($\exists$x A)[y\k] =$\exists$u (A[x\u])[y\k], otherwise, where u is not present in the formula and [x\u] only takes place for free variables.

Can anyone explain intuitively where these rules come from? I would like to better understand why they are defined as such. (Some of the rules may contain errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not sure to understand your symbolism*...

1) $(∃x A)[y/x] = ∃x A$. In a nutshell : we cannot substitute a variable that is *bound*, i.e. that is in the *scope* of the quantifier $∃$ (the same with $\forall$)

2) I think that you are considering : $(∃x A)[k/y] = ∃x A[k/y]$, i.e. we replace a *variable* $y$ with a *term* $k$ into the formula. If $x,k$ are not present in the formula, then the leading quantifier has no "role" whatever, and then we can ignore it.

3) Must be : $(∃x A)[k/y] = ∃u (A[u/x])[k/y]$. In this case $x$ is present in $A$ and thus - in order to avoid mistakes - we first replace $x$ with a *new* variable $x$; this is : $∃u A[u/x]$.

*Note* : $u$ must not be present in $A$ nor in the *term* $t$.

Comment: Indeed, good explanation... but why is that so? I realize it's a definition and needs no further explanation as such, but is there a particular reason for the definition?

Comment: @Tony - the simplest way is: try to perform the "forbidden" substitution and see what happens.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand, the forbidden substitution can be completed easily... Is it possible to give an example?

Comment: @Tony - example for 1) $∃x (x=0)$ sound true in arithmetic. Now subst $x$ with $y$ : $∃x (y=0)$. What does it mean ?

Comment: I see, it's not a well formed sentence indeed.... However, it would be if the quantifier was replaced as well.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Renaming bound variables is allowed, provided we do not introduce "unwanted bounds". Example : $\exists y (y=x+1)$ and $\exists z (z=x+1)$ have the same meaning. But if you change $\exists y (y=x+1)$ into $\exists x (x=x+1)$ we make a mistake.